# Database design decision

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, jpa

I'm going to design a merchant application. After merchants are registered with the system they will be able to add their products, discounts, price etc. And there is smart mobile apps to visit each merchants and their products.

So regarding the database (hope to use MySQL) design I have three options.

1. Use one database and use single table structure to maintain catalog with column called merchant_id.
2. Use one database and create same table structure per each merchant with unique prefix in table name.
3. Use separate database with table structure for each merchant when they registers with the system. In this case will maintain a master DB to keep merchant's db information.

We are developing a single application to cater all the merchant's and customers requests and there will be a lot of merchants and customers interact with the system.

Currently we are planning to use Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA.

So I'm troubling with get the correct decision in terms of scalability and maintainability or etc. Your expertise advices/recommendation are highly appreciated.

Comment: If the application is having only CRUD operation with minimal relation layer then its good to go with NOSQL db's like mongodb, easy integration with spring-data and if mobile app is hybrid then json layer data will be more efficient as well.

Comment: For a multi tenant system I would rule out 2) ... if 1) or 3) is the right choice depends on requirements not mentioned here: Do you plan to scale out or allow your merchants to take snapshots of *their* data? Do you plan allowing to create sandbox instances for demo/testing purposes?

Comment: Let's stick with MySQL as the question is not about going relational or no-sql.

Comment: Some expected numbers would help. How many merchants? 10k..10M? How many products?

Comment: number of products are unlimited.

Comment: I am not asking the theoretical limits, but the expected numbers on short, mid and long term.

Comment: This has been asked many times on SO

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan can you provide a few urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Use one database and use single table structure to maintain catalog
>   with column called merchant_id.

This is the easiest route to take.

**Pros**

- Low maintenance. Any changes to the DB make it to one schema / database.

**Cons**

- Does not scale beyond X merchants and N transactions per second on the database.

> 2) Use one database and create same table structure per each merchant
>   with unique prefix in table name.

This is a hybrid model of sorts, and writing the SQL and trying to track which prefix belongs to which app can be messy if you do not handle it correctly.

**Pros**

- Can scale a little better

**Cons**

- Maintenance overhead on each table; such as adding a new column called `created` to the table `user` requires you to modify `user_111` and `user_121` etc
- You can possibly mix up queries by attempting to join `user_111` with `access_121`.

> Use separate database with table structure for each merchant when they
>   registers with the system. In this case will maintain a master DB to
>   keep merchant's db information.

This provides the most scale but also gives you the most maintenance overhead.

**Pros**

- Can scale each database individually based on the type of customer you have and the traffic they provide.

**Cons**

- High maintenance for each database because individual parameters are tweaked at the DB level too (SSD / Shared buffers / fsync time with the disk / write caches etc ).

If you're starting out by designing a system where you will not know what kind of traffic it will attract on day 1, choose #1. Should the traffic be unexpectedly large, you can always scale vertically and place the high traffic customers on another db later (through a hashing mechanism that puts the customers into db buckets )

If you expect the site traffic to be large enough and already have capacity planned out for the customers, go for #3. You must bear the brunt of the maintenance overhead, but at least you get to scale each database based on the traffic that hits it.

I'm not a fan of #2 since I've seen that approach let down some products that implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion option 1 is the way to go. The benefit I see is that you can work over this table with aggregate queries to perform calculations over each merchant, e.g. your admin view wants to see the top 20 merchants with the highest number of products uploaded.

The drawback you might see in option 1 is that this table will be huge. This can be addressed with partitioning techniques and properly chosen indexes.

Option 2 and 3 are not nice because they introduce redundancy in your schema.

Also you can consider that with JPA your entity classes naturally map to tables, but I think table prefixes per merchant would be painful to hack with JPA. This is also a +1 for option 1.

What benefits do you see in option 2 and 3? I don't really see any advantage, only drawbacks.

Comment: If one day merchant requested a separate system we have to provide it without any pain do think option one can do it as well.

Comment: What is "separate system"? You mean deploying the backend with a brand new database for him?